# jQuery ajax response received as Javascript Object instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble with this.

In a file.js write the following codes.

```
function fleet_vssl_list(callbackFunc){
    func_name = "Get_Vssl_Fleet";
    let responseObject = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_rank_vssl_fleet.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: `func_name=${func_name}`,
        success: function(responseObject){
            console.log(responseObject);
            responseObject = JSON.parse(responseObject);
            console.log(responseObject);
            vssl_fleet = responseObject.vssl_fleet;
        }
    });
}
```

And as for PHP file I wrote as follows.

```
function vssl_list(){
    $conn = StartConn();
    $qry = ("select vssl_name from vessel");
    $qry_exec = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($qry_exec) > 0){
        $results = mysqli_fetch_all($qry_exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach ($results as $my_row){
            $vssl[] = $my_row["vssl_name"];
        }
        StopConn($conn);
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'vssl' => $vssl
            )
        );
    }
    else{
        $results = "No Vessel Data Found !!!";
        StopConn($conn);
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'vssl' => $results
            )
        );
    }
}
```

In the console, I receive as below image.
[Upper one if before JSON.parse and bottom one is after JSON.parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GDDl.png)

In the same .js file I wrote another function as follows.

```
function insert_dept_crew(){
    let responseObject = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert_update_delete_obd_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data_string,
        success: function(responseObject){
            //responseObject = JSON.parse(responseObject);
            console.log(responseObject);
        },
    });
}
```

And as for PHP, I wrote as follows just to test the results.

```
function insert_new(){
    $func_name = "Insert_Departure_Crew";
    $cdc = 12345;
    $rank = "MST";
    $rank_sd = "MST";
    $vssl_id = 1;
    $fleet_id = 1;
    $dept_dt = "20200225";
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'func_name' => $func_name,
            'cdc' => $cdc,
            'rank' => $rank,
            'rank_sd' => $rank_sd,
            'vssl_id' => $vssl_id,
            'fleet_id' => $fleet_id,
            'dept_dt' => $dept_dt
        )
    );
}
```

I have blocked the code line JSON.parse and I receive in console as follow.
[I can see it as Javascript Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xSSx.png)

If I unblock the JSON.Parse in insert_dept_crew function, I got error. When I check with my PHP file, the return was solid JSON as follow.

```
{"func_name":"Insert_Departure_Crew","cdc":12345,"rank":"MST","rank_sd":"MST","vssl_id":1,"fleet_id":1,"dept_dt":"20200225"}
```

please help me with this inconsistency.

Comment: This is because jQuery automatically detects a JSON response and parses it to an object for you. If you call `JSON.parse` again on the object you see the error. Technically you shouldn't need to do it in the first example, assuming the response contains the correct `content-type` header

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The javascripts part are in same file. If jQuery automatically detects JSON, why it is not converted to Javascript Object in first source? I really don't kow content-type header. Can you please explain it.

Comment: Add to your `$.ajax({ dataType : "json" ...` to explicitly tell jquery that you want json back and not a string

Answer (score 0):

Got it...
I figured it out. Thanks to @freedomn-n and @RoryMcCrossan, I noticed that I used dataType in second jQuery, because I thought that it was for sending data. But it was for jQuery to expect what type of data will be returned.